# Unable to retrieve records from database

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to retrieve a record with this:

```
var users = User.find({ username: "andy" }).then(function(users){
    return users;
});

console.log(users);
return res.send(users);
```

But I get returned:

```
{
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log()` is outside the `then()` statement hence it's being executed before `User.find()` completes and all you get is an unfulfilled `promise` (not the query results). Try:

```
var users = User.find({ username: "andy" }).then(function(users){
  console.log(users);
  res.send(users);
  return users;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your code like this, based on the waterline examples:

```
Users.find({username:'andy'}).exec(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(500, {error: err});
  }

  return res.json(result);
});
```